# Wordpress Avada Theme - Square Payment Issues removing Woocommerce checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, square

Having issues removing checkout fields that is not needed. When client pays through PayPal, there is no problem. But through Square, its showing the following error when I remove `billing_country, billing_address_1, billing_city, billing_state and billing_postcode`:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[category] => INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR
[code] => INVALID_ENUM_VALUE
[detail] => “ is not a valid enum value for `billing_address.country`.
[field] => billing_address.country
)

)
Order status changed from Pending payment to Failed.
```

As it shows in the code, it is requiring billing_address.country. So I added that field again and when I try to submit the payment, it shows me the following error:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[category] => INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR
[code] => MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER
[detail] => Missing required parameter.
[field] => card_nonce
)

)
Order status changed from Pending payment to Failed.
```

I did some research and apparently its stopped becoming a Woocommerce issue and it became a theme issue.

Have contacted Avada's support, but no response from them so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me: disconnect square, log into square in the same browser, connect square in wordpress and ensure there is a test product of at least $1. Worked.

Comment: Thanks for the help but didn't work for me. Are you using avada theme too?

Comment: Yeah i have avada theme and this was the solution for me